# How to find a sub document in mongoose without using _id fields but using multiple properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, subdocument

I have a sample schema like this -

```
Comment.add({
    text:String,
    url:{type:String,unique:true},
    username:String,
    timestamp:{type:Date,default:Date}
});
Feed.add({
    url:{type:String, unique:true },
    username:String,
    message:{type:String,required:'{PATH} is required!'},
    comments:[Comment],
    timestamp:{type:Date,default:Date}
});
```

Now, I don't want to expose the _id fields to the outside world that's why I am not sending it to the clients anywhere. 
Now, I have two important properties in my comment schema (username,url)
What I want to do is update the content of the sub document that satisfies

1. feed.url
2. comment.url
3. comment.username

if the `comment.username` is same as my client value `req.user.username` then update the `comment.text` property of that record whose url was supplied by client in `req.body.url` variable.

One long and time consuming approach I thought is to first find the feed with the given url and then iterating over all the subdocuments to find the document which satisfies the `comment.url==req.body.url` and then check if the `comment.username==req.user.username` if so, update the comment object.
But, I think there must be an easier way of doing this?
I already tried  -

```
db.feeds.update({"username":"harshitladdha93@gmail.com","comments.username":"harshitladdha3@gmail.com","comments.url":"test"},{$set:{"comments.$.text":"updated text 2"}})
```

found from http://www.tagwith.com/question_305575_how-to-find-and-update-subdocument-within-array-based-on-parent-property

but this updates even when the `comments.url` or `comments.username`matches other sub documents

and I also tried

```
db.feeds.distinct("comments._id",{"comments.url":req.body.url})
```

to find the _id of document associated with the `url` but it returns all the `_id` in the subdocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off - you should not rely on `_id` not being seen by the outside world in terms of security. This is a very bad idea for a multitude of reasons (primarily REST and also the fact that it's returned by default with all your queries).

Now, to address your question, what you want is the `$elemMatch` operator. This says that you're looking for something where the specified sub-document within an array matches multiple queries.

E.g.

```
db.feeds.update({
    "username":"harshitladdha93@gmail.com",
    comments: {
        $elemMatch: {
            username: "harshitladdha3@gmail.com",
            url: "test"
        }
    }
}, {$set: {"comments.$.text":"updated text 2"}})
```

If you don't use `$elemMatch` you're saying that you're ok with the document if any of the comments match your query - i.e. if there is a comment by user "harshitladdha3@gmail.com", and separate comment has a url "test", the document will match unless you use `$elemMatch`